# Legendre Differential Equation (rearrange)

Tags: differential

Legendre differential equation:
$$
(1-x^2) \, y'' - 2x y' + \alpha(1+\alpha)y = 0 \, 
$$

which it can also be written as:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( (1-x^2) \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \right) + \alpha(1+\alpha)y = 0 \ 
$$

how did we reach equation two from equation one. I don't get it please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the basic rule $\frac{dfg}{dy} = f\frac{dg}{dx}+g\frac{df}{dx}$

So $\frac{d(1-x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}}{dx} = 1-x^2*y'' -2x*y'$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx}) = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = y’’$

Comment: what about -2xy'' why did it disappear

Comment: @a_alhm it is the basic rule of differentiation, from second equation if you differentiate the first term you get the first equation

Comment: @a_alhm thank you for pointing that out. If you differentiate $(1-x^2)$ you get $-2x$ then because of the $y$, you have to multiply by $\frac{dy}{dx} =y’$